# Redirect to Telegram by URL scheme from app

Tags: ios, redirect, telegram, url-scheme

In my app I have a button that allow users to share their experience via Telegram. I am currently using the following scheme to redirect:

```
tg://msg?text=Hello&to=+42333
```

As I understand this scheme allows to share text to the user if that user is in your contacts. But all what happens is redirection to Telegram, not Telegram user directly. So this scheme is not working properly, or I'm doing something wrong. 
I've used this docs:  http://tsfkb.wikidot.com/tips:ios:urischeme

Answer (score 3):

This is a wrong `tg://` format. Currently, official Telegram clients support these formats:

`tg://join?invite=`

`tg://addstickers?set=`

`tg://msg_url?`

`tg://confirmphone?`

`tg://socks?`

`tg://proxy?`

`tg://resolve/?domain=`

As you see, what you're trying to do is NOT possible in official clients so far.